# Winforms MVP show mdi child form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp

Guys i have problem with MVP design pattern becouse am not shure how can i show child view in parent form.
My view does not have `MdiParent` property. Can i manually create it in view interface?

Very ugly look to every form opens in a new window!

**I have two presenters:**

1. MainPresenter (represent mainForm(parent) logic)
2. TaskPresenter (represent logic for save,insert,delete logic)

**Two View interfaces:**

1. IMainView
2. ITaskView

**And two winforms:**

1. MainForm - mainwindow(parrent mdi form)
2. TaskForm

Check code:

**MainPresenter**

```
public class MainPresenter
{
    private readonly IMainView view;

    private List<ITaskModel> tasks;

    // Constructor
    public MainPresenter(IMainView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.Init();
        this.tasks = new List<ITaskModel>();
    }

    // Initialize
    private void Init()
    {
        this.view.AddTask += AddTask;
    }

    // Add task
    private void AddTask(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Show as MDI CHILD 
    }
}
```

**IMainView**

```
  public interface IMainView 
  {
        event EventHandler<EventArgs> AddTask;
  }
```

**TaskPresenter**

```
public class TaskPresenter 
{
    private readonly ITaskView view;
    private List<ITaskModel> tasks;

    private bool isNew = true;
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    // Constructor
    public TaskPresenter(ITaskView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.Initialize();
    }

    // Initialize
    public void Initialize()
    {
        tasks = new List<ITaskModel>();

        view.SaveTask += Save;
        view.NewTask += New;
        view.PrevTask += Previous;
        view.NextTask += Next;
    }

    private void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void New(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }     
    private void Next(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void Previous(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void BlankTask()
    {   
    }
    private void LoadTask(ITaskModel task)
    { 
    }
}
```

**ITaskView**

```
public interface ITaskView
{
    String TaskName { get; set; }
    String TaskPriority { get; set; }
    DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    DateTime? DuoDate { get; set; }

    event EventHandler<EventArgs> SaveTask;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> NewTask;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> NextTask;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> PrevTask;
}
```

**And here is MainForm**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainView
{
    MainPresenter Presenter;

    // Construcor
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Events
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> AddTask;

    // On load
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Presenter = new MainPresenter(this);
    }

    // On click add task btn
    private void addTaskBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(AddTask != null)
        {
            // When is this event triggered i want to show another child form for adding new task
            AddTask(this, EventArgs.Empty); 
        }
    }
}
```

So how can i show `TaskView` as child in `MainView`? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**UIApplication it is Windows Forms Application but output type Class Library.
Add referance MVPFramework**

MainForm

```
public partial class MainForm : Form , IMainView
{
    [Resolve]
    public IMainControl mainControl;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public bool ShowAsDialog()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void openChildFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainControl.OnOpenChildForm();
    }
}
```

Child Form

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form , IChildView
    {
        public ChildForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool ShowAsDialog()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        public object MDIparent
        {
            set
            {
                this.MdiParent = (Form)value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**CoreApplication it is class Library**

IMainControl

```
 public interface  IMainControl :IControl
  {
      void OnOpenChildForm();
  }
```

MainControl

```
public class MainControl  :IMainControl
    {
        [Resolve]
      public IApplicationController applicationController;
      public void OnOpenChildForm()
      {
       IChildControl TransfersOnTheWayControl = applicationController.Resolve<IChildControl>();
       TransfersOnTheWayControl.Run();
      }
    }
```

IChildControl

```
 public interface IChildControl :IControl
      {
         void Run();
      }
```

IMainView

```
public interface  IMainView :IView
{

}
```

IChildView

public interface  IChildView :IView
      {

```
      bool ShowAsDialog();`enter code here`

      object MDIparent { set; }
  }
```

IMainPresenter

```
public interface  IMainPresenter :IPresenter
 {

 }
```

IChildPresenter

```
public interface  IChildPresenter :IPresenter
 {
   bool Ask();
 }
```

MainPresenter

```
public class MainPresenter :BasePresenter<IMainView>, IMainPresenter
 {

 }
```

ChildPresenter

```
public class ChildPresenter : BasePresenter<IChildView>, IChildPresenter
    {

       public bool Ask()
       {
            this.Init();
            bool res = View.ShowAsDialog();
            ApplicationController.ClearInstance<IChildView>();
            return res;
       }

        public override void Init()
        {
            View.MDIparent = ApplicationController.GetMainFrom<IMainPresenter>();
            base.Init();
        }
    }
```

**LauncherApplication it is Console Application but output type Windows Form.**

```
 class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                IApplicationController applicationController = new ApplicationController(new ServicesContainerAdapter());

                applicationController


                    //RegisterView
                    .RegisterView<IMainView, MainForm>()
                    .RegisterView<IChildView, ChildForm>()


                    //RegisterPresenter
                    .RegisterPresenter<IMainPresenter, MainPresenter>()
                    .RegisterPresenter<IChildPresenter, ChildPresenter>()


                    //RegisterController
                    .RegisterController<IMainControl, MainControl>()
                    .RegisterController<IChildControl, ChildControl>();



                IMainPresenter mainPresenter = applicationController.Resolve<IMainPresenter>();
                mainPresenter.Init();

                Application.Run((Form)mainPresenter.FormObject);
            }
       }
```

Comment: can you post the source code of the BasePresenter and IPresenter, IView? Also which MVPFramework are you referencing?